# Shortcuts for <activity-alias> disappear on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

I've adopted a legacy app for a complete rewrite, and as a result, the starting activity has been renamed. To cope with users having placed a shortcut to my app from their home screen, I've added an `activity-alias` that points from the old name to the new.

Previously:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled.NoAnimation" />
```

Now:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.StartActivity_"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled.NoAnimation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity-alias
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:targetActivity=".activities.StartActivity_"/>
```

This works great for various devices I tested between 2.1 and 4.0. On Jelly Bean (4.1 & 4.2), however, I see that the default launcher is now removing the launch icon.

What's worse is that in some tests, the upgrade *doesn't show the app whatsoever*, only revealing it from the application list on the *second* install. There seems to be no rhyme or reason; sometimes the app just goes missing.

I've toyed with swapping the `IntentFilter`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.StartActivity_"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled.NoAnimation" />
<activity-alias
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:targetActivity=".activities.StartActivity_" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

ADB doesn't seem to like that very much:

> No Launcher activity found!
>   The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

For completeness: adding the `IntentFilter` to both activity names keeps the home screen shortcut, but shows two apps in the applications list.

How can I migrate and keep all my users satisfied?

Comment: The problem with the app not appearing at all appears to be specific to the 4.2 emulator. I couldn't reproduce it on other devices or the 4.1 emulator. Nevertheless, the launch shortcut disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug specific to the 4.2 emulator with the stock launcher.

The app in question is a very popular app in the Dutch market. As more devices will be migrating to Jelly Bean, I'll keep a close eye on any issues that might be related.

Of course if anybody encounters this in the wild, I'd be eager to hear about it.

Answer (score 2):

On Android 4.2.2, moving the launcher intent filter to another activity or alias causes all shortcuts, widgets, and the system app list icon to disappear.  This bug occurs on devices and emulators.  This issue does not happen in Android 4.1.2.  I have filed this bug here:

App launcher shortcuts and widgets disappear after changing launcher activity
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54720

Comment: Nobody seemed to acknowledge or admit that this is an actual bug at Google.   So now I am confused: is this a bug or not?

Comment: Haven't heard anything from Google. The self answer below says that this only affected the emulator but I never had a chance to test whether or not that is the case. I'm curious if it's fixed in the Android 4.4 emulator though.